# Почему студия предлагает изменить iterable List на Sequence

Tags: android, android-studio, list, kotlin

При множественном преобразовании студия всегда предлагает преобразовать iterable List, например:

```
     list.map{}.map{}
```

в Sequence и затем снова менять на List

```
list.asSequence().map{}.map{}.toList()
```

В моем случае никаких преимуществ по времени я не обнаружил. Поэтому у меня вопрос,- в каких случаях нужно преобразовывать iterable в Sequence, а в каких случаях не стоит этого делать?

Comment: Как именно предлагает? Прям активно указывает на это или просто есть опция, когда курсов на той строчке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разница между `list.map{}.map{}` и `list.asSequence().map{}.map{}.toList()` заключается в том, что в первом случае каждый `map{}` по факту будет простым циклом, который будет перебирать элементы списка, преобразовывать, класть в другой список и отправлять дальше.
А во втором случае поведение будет аналогично `stream`'у в Java, т.е. элементы будут по очереди проходить всю цепочку преобразований без создания промежуточных коллекций.

Последовательности следует использовать если вы работаете с большими коллекциями. Для небольших коллекций обычный подход может оказаться быстрее, но будет потреблять чуть больше памяти.

**UPD**

Еще один не совсем очевидный, но важный момент. Если цепочка будет например такой.

```
list.map{}.map{}.take(2);
list.asSequence().map{}.map{}.take(2).toList();
```

То в первом случае у вас обработаются ВСЕ элементы списка, а потом будут взяты 2 штуки, а во втором будут обработаны только 2 первых элемента.

**UPD** Наткнулся на [статью с очень хорошими иллюстрациями](https://typealias.com/guides/kotlin-sequences-illustrated-guide/)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]